# Do something when the route changes (Iron Router - Meteor)

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I would like to do a "Session.set()" when the route starts and do another one when it stops.

```
  var boxDisplaying = {
     onBeforeAction: function() {
       console.log("Box is opened");
       Session.set('boxIsOpen', true);
       this.next();
     },
     onStop: function(){
       Session.set('boxIsOpen', false);
       console.log("Box is closed");
     }
  };
```

(The other router's declaration part is ok and running well. I think I missed something about "onBeforeAction" and "onStop".)

The problem is that both of them are called when it starts and stops. I want "onBeforeAction" called when we start using the route and "onStop" when we stop. How can I make it work ?

Thanks.

Comment: where do you connect boxDiplaying with the router? can you show that code?

Comment: Thanks, but I solved it yesterday. There was a callback to this route, then every time I go/quit the route it's automatically called a second time. It works fine now :)